# UE4 tools (add on) for exporting fbx is not working for me

Tags: export, add-on

I don't know what to do, I followed exactly what Jayanaman did on his video about fbx exporting but I get an error.
[image: this error is ginormous]

Comment: Please add the error as text to the question of text. Otherwise no search engine will find related questions. "Tangent space can only be computed for tris/quads, aborting".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According the error "Tangent space can only be computed for tris/quads, aborting":

You might have a mesh containing a face with more then 4 vertices (BMesh). You can make sure to triangulate your mesh or fix your mesh manually. And try again.